# Show that the sequence $a_n=\frac{cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}$ converges to $0$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence, epsilon-delta

**Question:** Show that the sequence $a_n=\frac{cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}$ converges to $0$.

**My attempt:**
Need to show that $\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n>N \implies|a_n-0|<\varepsilon.$

Fix $\epsilon>0$.

We have $\left|a_n-0\right|=\left|\frac{cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}\right|$.

Since $cos(n^2+n)$ is bounded by $-1$ and $1$, we then have

$\left|\frac{cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}\right|\le\left|\frac{1}{n^2}\right|$
$=\frac{1}{n^2}$.

Then $\frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon \implies n^2>\frac{1}{\epsilon} \implies n>\sqrt\frac{1}{\epsilon}$

So choose $N=\lfloor\sqrt\frac{1}{\epsilon}\rfloor+1$ and the definition is satisfied. **Q.E.D.**

Not sure about this one so I would appreciate some input. Thanks

Comment: This is correct.  What were you unsure of?

Comment: Looks fine to me.

Comment: And the main question: are you forced to prove it from the definition? If not, there are much easier methods.

Comment: Mainly unsure about the jump from $\frac{cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}$ to $\frac{1}{n^2}$and also the change from $\le$ to $<$ I guess

Comment: @Shansss from here $\left|\frac{cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}\right|\le \frac{1}{n^2}\le \frac 1n$ you can conclude directly by squeeze theorem.

Comment: Putting squeeze theorem aside for a second, why am I allowed to just go from $\le$ to $<$ in the proof?

Comment: @Shansss The $\le$ is given  for $\left|\frac{cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}\right|\le \frac{1}{n^2}$ and $<$ is choosen in order to have $\frac{1}{n^2}<\epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply note that

$$-\frac1{n^2}\le\frac{\cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}\le\frac1{n^2}$$

thus by squeeze theorem since $\frac1{n^2}\to 0$ we have that

$$\frac{\cos(n^2+n)}{n^2}\to 0$$

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct, but if you want to make it easier, please observe that
$$
\frac1{n^2}<\frac1n,
$$
so it is enough to take $N=\lfloor 1/\epsilon\rfloor+1$.